# People who are in the age bracket of 50-60 year old

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you call these people using one word?

Comment: People in their fifties.

Comment: Why do you need one word? For those who are curious, there is the so-called [baby boomer generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers) people aged between 52 and 70.

Comment: I've heard the term "old fart".

Comment: Some of us call them young.

Comment: Fifty-somethings

Comment: "Late boomers" might work.

Answer (score 4):

You could call them a **quinquagenarian**

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quinquagenarian

```
adjective
1. 50 years of age.
2. between the ages of 50 and 60. 
noun
3. a person who is 50 years old or whose age is between 50 and 60.
```

Unlike septuagenarian and octogenarian, the 70s and 80s equivalents, this word is very rarely used, so people would likely not understand, though they might be able to guess the meaning since the prefix "quin" appears in words like "quintet" and "quintuplets".